# Change thumbs size in TTThumbsViewController

Tags: iphone, three20

Does anybody know if there is a way to increase the size of the images on the grid in a TTThumbsViewController in the three20 framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the `TTThumbsViewController`, you'll have to edit that file.

Change the `kThumbSize` to the size you want, and `kThumbnailRowHeight` to that value+4 (for the padding).

Then, in `tableView:cell:willAppearAtIndexPath:`, set:

```
 thumbsCell.thumbSize = kThumbSize;
```

so the thumbs know what size to be.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create a category of `TTThumbsDataSource` 
Copy the code below into a file ThumbnailDataSource.m and create a similiar headerfile.
Include the header file in your `TTThumbsViewController` subclass. Set `kThumbSize` to the size you want.

```
#import <Three20/Three20.h>

@implementation TTThumbsDataSource(ThumbnailDataSource)
- (void)        tableView: (UITableView*)tableView
                     cell: (UITableViewCell*)cell
    willAppearAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[TTThumbsTableViewCell class]]) {
        TTThumbsTableViewCell* thumbsCell = (TTThumbsTableViewCell*)cell;
        thumbsCell.delegate = _delegate;
        thumbsCell.columnCount = [self columnCount];
        thumbsCell.thumbSize = kThumbSize;
    }
}

@end
```