# three20 and orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I am using three20 for displaying thumbnails. It's working perfectly. But I need to resize the thumbnail. Is it possible to resize the thumbnail and Bool shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is also not supported

I am implement to check the orientation in viewdidload method

> TTDeviceOrientationIsPortrait()
>   TTDeviceOrientationIsLandscape();

But it is not working in **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation** method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fixing the issue by using **NSNotification** for **orientation**

> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
>   selector:@selector(orientationDidChange:)
>   name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

and refer the link by changing size

[Change thumbs size in TTThumbsViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945859/change-thumbs-size-in-ttthumbsviewcontroller)